# UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native library (com/sun/jna/android-x86-64/libjnidispatch.so) not found in resource path (.)

Tags: java, android, packet-capture, pcap4j

i'm develop android app for sniffing packets from device.
I'm using pcap4j library, but when call Pcaps.getDevByAddress(), launches the exception.
Can you help me?

This is snipped code:

```
InetAddress destAddr = parsedPacket;
```

`PcapNetworkInterface nif =Pcaps.getDevByAddress(destAddr);`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this might still be an issue for you. Have you added both dependencies to you classpath?

Add the following to your pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.pcap4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>pcap4j-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.3</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.pcap4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>pcap4j-packetfactory-static</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.3</version>
 </dependency>
   ...
</dependencies>
```

Also make sure you have installed pcaplib-dev on your machine. Depends on OS how to install it.

Did you perform these steps?

If so, have you given java root access (assuming you are on linux)? I have seen people getting issues after they used the set_cap command. Please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should add JNA as aar:

```
implementation 'net.java.dev.jna:jna:5.5.0@aar'
```

ref: https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/www/FrequentlyAskedQuestions.md#jna-on-android